# npm -v shows older version after updated too

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed npm using `sudo apt-get install npm` and `npm -v`
it shows 1.3.10. After i have updated using `npm install -g npm` and downloaded as

> npm@3.3.8 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

but it shows as 1.3.10.
How can i update npm.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: I have updated my system to Ubuntu 15.10, and I have updated npm by running `npm install -g npm` two times. Currently system working on 3.5.0 version, couldn't find the reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo npm install npm@latest`. 
This is the easiest way to update npm to the new version.

Comment: It's install old version, i think my system allows that 1.3.10 version